# Extract ZIP and move all files to parent directory

Tags: yeoman

I'm only just getting started with Yeoman, trying to create a Generator that downloads WordPress, unzips it, and then proceeds to download my own WordPress starter theme.

The problem I'm having is that when I extract the `latest.zip` from wordpress.org (using `this.extract()`) it contains a `wordpress/` directory resulting in my directory structure being `my-project/wordpress/` rather than `my-project/`.

I've tried moving, copying and deleting the `wordpress/` directory with various degrees of success; using `this.fs.copy()` I actually managed to get the files in the correct folder, but when trying to delete the original `wordpress/` directory the user has to confirm deletion of every single file (not ideal). When I tried `this.fs.move()` I had to confirm each and every move instead.

I've found similar gulp/node.js questions on here, but I would prefer to use Yeoman's built in `this.fs` API.

Please note that I am aware of YEOPress but this is mostly for learnig purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the Node Package fs-extra instead as it deletes or moves without confirmation.